# How to trigger checkbox from controller in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

Here is my HTML code

```
<ion-item nav-clear menu-close class="item-icon-right" ng-repeat="a in result.result | filter: a.groupName=sortby">
<input type="checkbox" id="{{a.switchID}}" name="value1" style="display:none;" ng-change="send(a.deviceID,a.pinNumber,a.switchID,value1)" ng-model="value1" ng-true-value="'On'" ng-false-value="'Off'" value="{{value1}}"></input>
<label style="margin-left:-15px;" for="{{a.switchID}}"></label>
<div class="card" ng-click="card(a.switchID)" style="margin:-59px 0px -2px 51px;height:64px;width:100%" ng-class="{'class1': value1 == 'Off','class2': value1 == 'On'}"> <p style="margin-left:11px;font-size:18px;color:white;margin-top:8px;">{{a.alias}}</p>
    <p id = "{{a.switchID}}" style="font-size:16px;color:white;margin-top:8px;margin-right:11px;" class="pull-right">{{value1}}</p>
</div>
</ion-item>
```

Now by clicking on card i want to change the value of checkbox

Comment: Please present us (the relevant part of) your controller code and tell us what is not working.

Comment: Basically i have list of Bulb(checkbox) with details card which contains its status ON or OFF. If I click on bulb it changes details of status card but i want to change bulb(checkbox) value to be change when i click on card also

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: Sorry. My question was, how to change the state of checkbox by clicking on card and to trigger function of ng-change in checkbox.@Mike0

Comment: But i solved with the solution given below. Thank you all for replying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to reverse the value of your ng-model property

```
<div class="card" ng-click="value1 = !value1"
```

Comment: Yes its changing value but its no triggering the function of checkbox which i have mentioned for ng-change. @Sam

Comment: Thank you. With the use of your given solution I did. Like this:                                      ng-click="value1=!value1;send(a.deviceID,a.pinNumber,a.switchID,value1)" @Sam

Comment: I also suggest putting the html that is inside the ng-repeat inside a directive - keeps controller clean, tidier html and is way forward for angular2

Comment: Sure I'll look at it. Thank You @Sam